# combine/merge two php functions

Tags: php, wordpress, merge

I need to combine/merge two php functions, but I can't get the syntax right.

The first one (WordPress function) displays a link, with the text 'Next CD in Category', to the next post in my category:

`<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next CD in Category', TRUE) ?>`

The second one is used to display the link text in my site's different languages:

```
<?php echo SPEC($GLOBALS['_LANG']['Next CD in Category']) ?>
```

How do I combine these so that the 'Next CD in Category' link to uses the language function to display the link in different languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    next_post_link(
        '%link',
        SPEC($GLOBALS['_LANG']['Next CD in Category']),
        TRUE
    );
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', SPEC($GLOBALS['_LANG']['Next CD in Category']), TRUE) ?>
```

is it what are you looking for?